# Adobe flash player installed but not showing in IE

Tags: windows-server-2008, adobe-flash

I have installed adobe flash player 10.3 which is required for my application, in windows server 2008 R2. but when i am opening IE its not showing adobe is installed. Please help to run adobe flash player in server 2008

Comment: Internet Explorer 32bit or 64bit?  Flash Player 10 did not support 64bit IE.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the version for IE, and not the one for Firefox or other browsers?

Comment: david its 64 bit, are you sure flash player 10.3 doesnt support 64 bit????

Comment: @sohail Yes. See http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/finally-adobe-releases-a-64-bit-flash-player/4033 . You will have both 32 bit and 64 bit IE installed in 64 bit Windows. There's more information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/05/29/q-a-64-bit-internet-explorer.aspx